# Strange syntax highlight in Notepad++ for Fortran fixed source form

Tags: fortran, notepad++

When I use Notepad++ for Fortran coding in fixed source form, strange syntax highlights occur.

A letter in variables is somehow highlighted (see the picture below), though it doesn't seem to be special.

In some variable names, only a letter in the middle is highlighted:

[image: In some variable names, only a letter in the middle is highlighted]

The position of the highlighted letters seem to be fixed. Move the commands, the highlighted letters change (see the picture below).

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: First idea was fixed versus free formatted text, but this doesn't look like the case seen the placing of the lines like "C  Mean...". Is there somewhere a `<tab>` in the code?

Comment: I guess that is just a bug in Notepad++... Maybe you wanna try out a different editor? I would suggest VSCode and syntax highlighting via fortran-language-server.

Comment: Tab instead of four spaces indeed sounds plausible.

Comment: Try selecting menu => View => Show symbol => Show white space and Tab. That should clarify whether it is tab characters in your file that are causing the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The green bit is where the continuation character would have been..

In your program, select all the code (ctrl-A), then click on Edit/Blank Operations.  Select Tab to spaces.

If you wish the tabs to be replaced by spaces as you type, do the following.

In Notepad++, goto Settings/Preferences
Select Language from the box on the left.
In the box on the far right, under Tab Settings, tick replace by space

Note that this will hold for all future files.  If you must have tabs, like in makefiles, then you'll need to use Blank Operations/Space to tabs (leading).

Comment: You can change the tab option for each file type.